# regex from till string capture

Tags: php, regex, match

```
<h2 class="element">
name
</h2>
<div class="outerElement">
address
</div>
<h2 class="element">
name
</h2>
<div class="outerElement">
address
</div>
```

I need to get a regex that will get everything between `<h2 class="element">` till the next `<h2 class="element">` so I came up with this:

```
preg_match_all('/div class="outerElement"(.*?)div class="outerElement"/', $content, $elements);
```

but for some reason it ain't working (do I have to escape double quotes or what is the problem?

Comment: You shall not use regex to parse HTML: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/298479

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add "s" modifier to expression like this:

```
 '/div class="outerElement"(.*?)div class="outerElement"/s'
```

This is necessary to force multiline mode matching.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use regex here.
Use PHP DOM parse instead. Your task will be easier and less prone to errors.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php

Answer (score 0):

The following regex captures all the matches in group 1.

As you were saying, you will need to iterate over the matches with a preg_match_all.

For convenience, here is the regex in whitespace mode.

```
(?xs)                       # modes: whitespace, dot matches new line
(?<=<h2[ ]class="element">) # is there an element h2 tag behind us
\W*                         # match any non-word char (greedy)
(\w.*?)                     # capture a word char followed by any char (lazy)
<h2[ ]class="element"       # match the next class element
```

And here is a sample preg_match_all that uses this regex and returns the captured groups. I have tested it with your sample string. It works. :)

```
<?php 
$subject='<h2 class="element">
name
</h2>
<div class="outerElement">
address
</div>
<h2 class="element">
name
</h2>
<div class="outerElement">
address
</div>
';
preg_match_all('/(?xs)       # modes: whitespace, dot matches new line
(?<=<h2[ ]class="element">) # is there an element h2 tag behind us
\W*                         # match any non-word char (greedy)
(\w.*?)                     # capture a word char followed by any char (lazy)
<h2[ ]class="element"       # match the next class element
/s', $subject, $all_matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE | PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$size=count($all_matches[1]);
echo "<br />*****************<br />";
echo "Number of Matches: ".$size."<br />";
echo "*****************<br />";
for ($i=0;$i<$size;$i++) {
echo "Match number: ".($i+1)."<br />";
echo "At position: ".$all_matches[1][$i][1]."<br />";   
echo "Captured text: ".htmlentities($all_matches[1][$i][0])."<br />";
}
echo "End of Matches<br />";
echo "*****************<br /><br />";
?>
```

Finally, here is the output:

```
*****************
Number of Matches: 1
*****************
Match number: 1
At position: 22
Captured text: name </h2> <div class="outerElement"> address </div>
End of Matches
*****************
```

If I understood, this is what you were looking for.